# headless install of JIRA via Chef

Tags: automation, installation, jira, chef-infra

Has anyone experience doing a headless install of JIRA via Chef? (I'm working on an experiment to see if we can automate setting up new project environments quickly)

Using Chef I can start the Jira install like this...
    install MySQL
    add JIRA DB and user, grant priviliges
    template the response.varfile
    remote file download JIRA installer
    execute JIRA installer with the varfile
    copy the MySQL connector into the JIRA lib folder
    stop then start the JIRA service

...but there is a second stage where JIRA requires I open a brower and provide database and other creds to finish the configuration. The requests being sent look like they have unique tokens etc generated.

Approaches considered:
  * Use curl to fake the configuration - there is a unique token and there is a response which we'd have to consume.
  * Use xvfb and Selenium (or similar) to pretend to drive the browser - we've been unable to get this working successfully today.
  * Copy in hand-generated config files/DB - not a great long term plan, but again, we've had some special values that caused us issues.

JIRA's a popular product, anyone had any luck installing it via Chef?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends how far you want to take the installation. To get it to the point where someone can create the admin user how about not using the JIRA installer. Just unpack the standard tar.gz package, set the JIRA home in jira-application.properties and fix up the JIRA home/dbconfig.xml file. Add some plugin jar files to installed-plugins and you should be about ready.

Comment: thanks mdoar, without some nasty hack, I think that is the best option